# How to load data from external JSON into carousel

Tags: json, jsonp, sencha-touch, carousel

guys. I've started playing with Sencha Touch and I've hit the wall in my first attempt to create simple app that read JSON file and then put the content into carousel cell (there are 6).

Here is the code so far:

```
Ext.setup({ 
icon: 'icon.png',
glossOnIcon: false,
phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png', 
onReady: function() { 

  var arena_zapad = new Ext.Component({
    title: 'Arena Zapad',
    scroll: 'vertical',
    tpl: [
      '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div class="movie">',
          '<div class="title"><h2>{title}</h2></div>',
          '<div class="days">{days}</div>',
        '</div>',
      '</tpl>'        
      ]      
  });

  var refresh = function() {
    Ext.util.JSONP.request({
      url: 'arena_zapad.json',
      callbackKey: 'callback',
      callback: function(data) {
        arena_zapad.update(data)          
      }
    })  
  }

    new Ext.TabPanel({
        fullscreen: true,
        tabBar: {
            dock: 'bottom',
            layout: {pack: 'center'}
        },
        animation: 'slide',
        items: [{
            title: 'Movie Theaters',
            iconCls: 'monitor2',
            xtype: 'carousel',
            items: [
              { html: "Arena Mladost",
                cls: 'card card2'
                // I want the json data here instead of html text
              },{
                html: 'Arena West',
                cls: 'card card2'
            },{
                html: 'Арена The Mall',
                cls: 'card card3'
            },{
                html: 'Cineplex',
                cls: 'card card3'
            },{
                html: 'Cinema City',
                cls: 'card card3'
            },{
                html: 'M-TEL IMAX',
                cls: 'card card3'
            }]
        }, {
            title: 'Movies',
            html: 'Movies',
            iconCls: 'video_black2',
            cls: 'card card1'
        }, {
            title: 'Premier',
            html: 'Premier',
            iconCls: 'photo3',
            cls: 'card card3'
        }, {
            title: 'Favourites',
            html: 'Favourites',
            iconCls: 'favorites',
            cls: 'card card1'
        }, {
            title: 'About',
            html: 'About',
            iconCls: 'info2',
            cls: 'card card5'
        }]
    });
}
```

});

And here is the json file:

```
{
"movies": [
    {
        "days": "Digital: 12:15, 14:15, 16:15, 18:15, 20:15, 22:15 35MM: 11:15, 13:15, 15:15, 17:15, 19:15, 21:15, 23:15",
        "title": "TILT"
    },
    {
        "days": "9 февруари (сряда), 13:10, 15:30, 17:50, 19:00, 20:10, 21:20, 22:30",
        "title": "Бурлеска"
    },
    {
        "days": "9 февруари (сряда), 12:00, 16:15",
        "title": "Запознай се с малките"
    }
]
```

}

So basically I want to load that file, parse it and put it in the first carousel "cell" (and later to populate the other "cells"). I've looked at the documentation but I cannot figure it how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use JSONP to load if you're on the same domain. Just use Ext.Ajax.request. There is an example of loading carousel content from xml, the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this example? http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/build-ipad-app-sencha-touch

Very in-depth tutorial at building an app the pulls data from another source (I think it's Youtube, can't remember) and populates about 48 thumbnails that have clickable overlays - very cool.

Si